# URL rewrite to add a directory at start of url

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my website, all images/stylesheets are in the  /CMS/...  directory. Recently, our website  shifted to new server at a temporary url where they referenced like /newdirectory/CMS/...

How can we append  /newdirectory/ to all  /CMS/  calls?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 12):

Inside the **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newdirectory/CMS/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newdirectory/CMS/$1
```

This will perform a rewrite, so accessing *http://www.server.com/CMS/index.html* will actually serve the content of *http://www.server.com/newdirectory/CMS/index.html*

Note: This solution assumes that the CMS is the only thing being served for this domain.

If this domain is serving more than the CMS (and only the CMS should be redirected), then the following may be better:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/CMS/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newdirectory/$1
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a RewriteRule (or mod_rewrite) for this. You can use a simple RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch ^/CMS/(.*) http://tempserver.com/newdirectory/CMS/$1
```

Comment: It's slightly lower-weight and does not require mod_rewrite to be enabled. Neither of those points are really a problem in practice today, but it's still a nice technique.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using mod_rewrite, which most apache/linux servers have. Create a file called .htaccess in the docroot of your site with the contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/CMS/(.*)$      /newdirectory/CMS/$1    [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This method will make it transparent to the end user and no impact on current pagerank, SEO, etc value and all inbound links will be maintained.