# RealURL problems when using TYPO3 and Magento in one webroot

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, realurl

We have following setup:

The webroot contains two directories. One for Magento and one for TYPO3.

I have an additional ht.access which should rewrite some urls to use TYPO3. Everything else should go to Magento. This htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Indexes

Follow Symlinks

Options +FollowSymLinks
Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /cms/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^kurse(.*)$ /cms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^service(.*)$ /cms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kontakt(.*)$ /cms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^informationen(.*)$ /cms/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ /cms/typo3/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now when I call a url, lets say `http://host/informationen` RealURL redirects this to `http://host/cms/rmationen` which leads to "Path Segment errors"

I also tried / and /cms/ as RewriteBase. Nothing works as expected.

Is there any workaround to realize both systems using one domain?

Cheers
Matthias

Comment: You want to redirect or to rewrite ?

Comment: I need to rewrite. For SEO reasons I don't want to have a pathsegment like 'cms' in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the 'cms' redirect block first, as the [L] stops all further processing.

Comment: ps: if you have only 4 content pages, adding typo3 is an overkill. You could use magento's built in cms function or a lightweight php cms like www.grabaperch.com - that's just an opinion of course

Comment: Ah sorry for the mess I got sth wrong. The shop rewrite is at the bottom already I see.

Comment: We have a plenty pages. They just all start with 'kontakt,...'

Comment: Just a few hints: see this question about adding an additional directory to the path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228901/url-rewrite-to-add-a-directory-at-start-of-url - for starters, you didn't pass any parameters to the destination URL in your code. The rewrite would rather look like RewriteRule ^kontakt/(.*)$ /cms/kontakt/$1 [L]. Then again, this has probably nothing to do with realURL, you could turn it off for testing.