# Hide directories in URL using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the php extension as well as hiding the sub directories using .htaccess file in my domain. However, I do not have much knowledge regarding regex and I am really stuck here. Would really appreciate if someone could assist with this!

What I'm trying to achieve is:
www.example.com/index.php to www.example.com/index
www.example.com/assets/php/company.php to www.example.com/company

## CURRENT .htaccess FILE

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^assets/php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Currently, I could successfully remove the .php extension from the URL as well as achieving http://www.example.com/company but it displays a 404 Not Found Error. I believe I'm missing a RewriteCond line, but I do not know how to write it. Or do I require another htaccess file in /assets/php/?

Will really appreciate if someone could assist with this! Nevertheless, thanks for reading.

Cheers,

TY

Comment: what do you mean by "__hiding the sub directories__" ?

Comment: Are all your files in /assets/php/ ? Or are there other subdirectories to worry about? You can write rules to prepend those directories under certain URLs but only if they follow some sort of pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228901/url-rewrite-to-add-a-directory-at-start-of-url

Comment: @PedroLobito My apologies if I was unclear. The original URL was www.example.com/assets/php/company.php and I want to hide the assets & php folders. My desired outcome should be www.example.com/company

Comment: @ahoffner Besides my index.php which is at the public_html root folder, all the other php files are all within assets/php/. Do I need to have another htaccess file under /assets/php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /assets/php/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/php/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ assets/php/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi! Everything works fine after using your code, except the index page returns a not found. Any idea why?

Comment: The site is accessible at example.com but not when accessed through example.com/index.

Comment: Unless `/index` is a directory I believe `example.com/index` should also work by routing it to `example.com/assets/php/index.php`

Comment: actually, all the files in assets/php are working fine. Index is in the root folder at example.com/index.php. Is it possible to make it accessible through example.com/index too?

Comment: Thanks again, worked like a charm! I'm sorry for the many questions, but I have another folder which is root/administrator/php/admin.php but it is no longer able to access. Are there any ways to only make the rule application to the particular folder root/assets/php and leave the others alone?

Comment: Hmm ok try my updated rules for removing `.php` only from `/assets/php/` directory.

Comment: Thanks a million! You solved all the issues. I'll read up and refer to your solution to understand it. Cheers, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

USe This

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#enforce www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#forward all requests, except new/admin, to the 'new' directory without the user's awareness
RewriteRule  new/admin  -  [S=2]
RewriteRule  ^$ new/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, after I included the code, the website returned a 500 Internal Server Error error. How should I resolve this?

Comment: In yor dirctory exist new/admin folder?

Comment: I'm still getting the error with the container folder new/admin created. Would really appreciate if you could explain to me your answer regarding creating a 'new' directory?